# ARC Memory Management Changing Per Example

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

Note: I created a Test program so I can better understand how ARC works - I am having trouble implementing it in my real project.

I created a Test program to determine how ARC works - it works great! Here it is.

ViewController1:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var vc2:ViewController2?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("VC1 Initialized")
        addButton()
    }

    func addButton() {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("Go to VC2", for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        let vx = ViewController2()
        vx.VC1 = self
        vc2 = vx
        self.present(vc2!, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

ViewController2:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    weak var VC1:ViewController?
    weak var VC3:ViewController3?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("VC2 Initialized")
        addButton()
    }

    deinit {
         print("VC2 Deinitialized")
    }

    func addButton() {
        for i in 0..<2 {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height*0.5*CGFloat(i), width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height*0.5))
            button.backgroundColor = i == 0 ? .red : .blue
            button.setTitle("Go to VC\(i*2+1)", for: .normal)
            self.view.addSubview(button)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.tag = i
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        let tag = sender.tag
        if(tag == 0) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            let vc3 = ViewController3()
            vc3.ViewController2 = self
            VC3 = vc3
            self.present(VC3!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController3:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    var ViewController2:ViewController2?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("VC3 Initialized")
        addButton() 
    }

    deinit {
        print("VC3 Deinitialized")
    }

    func addButton() {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("Go to VC1", for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        self.ViewController2!.VC1!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What I was looking at was how to remove multiple pages at a time (as indicated by the button push on VC3 and it goes back to the main page) and still remove ARC memory. All goes well. You can see the output below of me doing these operations.

`Start program - push to page 2 - push to page. 1 - push to page 2 - push to page 3 - go to page 1`

```
VC1 Initialized
VC2 Initialized
VC2 Deinitialized
VC2 Initialized
VC3 Initialized
VC3 Deinitialized
VC2 Deinitialized
```

The problem I am incurring is in my actual program - when I use these methods above, it automatically calls deinit on the last object I created when I CREATE my new object. But it doesn't actually delete anything - the memory graph will show x number of items even though the deinit method is called.

```
import UIKIT

class myClass: UIViewController {

    weak var pageController:PageController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Initialized PC")
        presentThemes()
    }

    func presentThemes() {
        let pg = PageController(x: 1, controller: self)
        pageController = pg
        self.present(pageController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        print("Deinit")
    }
}
```

The output I am being provided is:

```
Initialized PC
```

On the first instance and is:

```
Deinit
Initialized PC
```

On the second instance. Any idea why Deinit is being called but the memory graph shows it there?

Comment: Nowhere in your code is there a `print("Deinit")`, so your output doesn't seem to come from the code you provided. It is incredibly unlikely that `deinit` would be called but the object still exist afterwards. Coupled with the fact that the output does not match your code, this suggest that you're not seeing what you think you're seeing. When you say it's different in a sample program than it is in your "actual program" then the solution is to keep simplifying your actual program until the two match.

Comment: Also do not test on the simulator! Simulated memory management is not memory management. :) Run on the device, preferably using a release build, if you really want to see what happens to your objects. This sounds like a good opportunity for you to use Instruments to track memory allocations.

Comment: I think better naming of your properties would help with your understanding (certainly mine!). With code like `vc3.ViewController2 = self` etc it's incredibly hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.